# How to fix "invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal hex number with leading zero digits into Go struct field CallArgs.value of type *hexutil.Big"?

Tags: contract-development, remix, metamask, ico, crowdsale

Using Remix and metamask, I have deployed a contract on the rinkeby network that contains a function that, when called will send unsold tokens to a specific address. The code for it is like this

```
  function finalizeCrowdsale() public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
    require(hasEnded());
    require(token.transfer(tokenWallet, remainingTokens));
    return true;
  }
```

When I attempt to call this function in remix (from the account which deployed the contract, which is the owner), I get an error

```
transact to JTokenCrowdsale.finalizeCrowdsale errored: Error: invalid 
argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal hex number with leading zero digits into 
Go struct field CallArgs.value of type *hexutil.Big
```

What causes this and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14682

> value should be an integer (in Wei) and not a fraction of an Ether.

Comment: To clarify this answer to the OP a little bit: You probably might have set gas or gasPrice to something with a leading zero instead of a value in Wei.